# Additional column in aggregate function

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables:

`EMP` table (table of employees):

```
CREATE TABLE EMP
(
"ID" NUMBER, 
"DEPT_ID" NUMBER, 
"NAME" VARCHAR2(30),
 PRIMARY KEY ("ID") ENABLE,  
 FOREIGN KEY ("DEPT_ID") REFERENCES DEPARTMENT ("ID") ENABLE
);
```

and `DEPARTMENT` table:

```
CREATE TABLE DEPARTMENT 
(
"ID" NUMBER, 
"NAME" VARCHAR2(30), 
 PRIMARY KEY ("ID")  
);
```

I want to write query, which will show

```
DEPARTMENT.ID | DEPARMTENT.NAME | COUNT of employees working at the department.
```

I know how to show id, but then I cannot show name. How to do that? DEPARTMENT NAMEs are not unique, so it complicates it. DEPARTMENT ID can be unallocated to any of employees.

Query:

```
select d.id, count(e.id)
from emp e
right join department d
on e.DEPT_ID = d.ID
group by d.id
order by d.id;
```

shows id and count, but without name.

Comment: Updated, in such simple case it shouldn't matter:).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just do this:

```
select d.id, d.name, count(e.id)
from emp e
right join department d
on e.DEPT_ID = d.ID
group by d.id, d.name
order by d.id;
```

Its not complicated by `department.name` not being unique, because the combination of `department.id and department.name` IS distinct..

Comment: It is working, thanks:). I forgot, that several elements can be in group clause.

Comment: Just to note that in some RDBMS (eg. PostgreSQL) you wouldn't need d.name in the group by clause, if d.id is the primary key.